# Spring Beans getting initialised twice for Entity Manager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am having a bean defined as below

```
 <bean id="batchManagementService" class="com.amdocs.dc.sprint.batch.service.BatchManagementServiceImpl" autowire-candidate="false">
     <property name="repository" ref="batchPersistenceRepository" />
     <property name="timeService" ref="batchTimeService" />     
     <property name="validator" ref="batchValidator" />
  </bean>
```

I am refering this bean in two places in different modules.
However it is getting initialised with two differnt values.

1. with the JDK proxy which performs correct DB transactions
2. with the implementor class directly "BatchManagementServiceImpl" as mentioned above.
   IN the second case the Entity manager is returning null causing all DB transactions to fail.

The implementor class contains transactional methods.
Any help on this will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you add more details? in order to help you better. By the information that you given, the problem could be anywhere.

Comment: You must be calling new BatchManagementServiceImpl() somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear from the description for me, but it sounds like your applicationContext is misconfigured within the modules. 
Maybe you try an approach like:
MODULE_A: 
  -applicationContextA.xml
MODULE_B (which should use MODULE_A's beans )
  -applicationContextB.xml
MODULE_C (which should use MODULE_B and MODULE_A  )
  -applicationContextC.xml

The **WRONG** approach is:

applicationContextA.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    ...
    <bean id="batchManagementService"...>
```

applicationContextB.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <import resource="applicationContextA.xml"/>
    <bean id=anotherBean...
```

applicationContextC.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <import resource="applicationContextB.xml"/>
    <bean id=anotherBean...
```

In this case, when applicationContextC is created, batchManagementService will be instantiated twice.

Try this one: 
applicationContextA.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    ...
    <bean id="batchManagementService"...>
```

applicationContextB.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <!--No import here! -->
    <!--<import resource="applicationContextA.xml"/>-->
    <bean id=anotherBean...
```

applicationContextC.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <!-- No import here -->
    <!--<import resource="applicationContextB.xml"/>-->
    <bean id=anotherBean...
```

applicationContextFull.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <import resource="applicationContextA.xml"/>
    <import resource="applicationContextB.xml"/>
    <import resource="applicationContextC.xml"/>
 </beans>
```

, and try to boot application context using applicationContextFull.xml. 
Hope this helps.